# Programmatically set the value of a multi-value field from multiple arrays

Tags: 8, webforms

I have 3 taxonomy vocabularies:

1. Fruits
2. Vegetables
3. Drinks

On the `Article` content type, I have set a multi-value entity reference field `field_article_all_items` referencing all of `Fruits`, `Vegetables` and `Drinks` taxonomy vocabularies.

Using the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module, I have created a webform with 3 elements:

- `fruits_category` which is a **non-required**, **multi-value** Entity Checkboxes element referencing the `Fruits` Taxonomy Vocabulary
- `vegetables_category` which is a **non-required**, **multi-value** Entity Checkboxes element referencing the `Vegetables` Taxonomy Vocabulary
- `drinks_category` which is a **non-required**, **multi-value** Entity Checkboxes element referencing the `Drinks` Taxonomy Vocabulary

Now on webform submit, I want to:

1. Create a new node of type `article`.
2. Set the values of `field_article_all_items` equal to all selected values
   from `fruits_category`, `vegetable_category` and `drinks_category`.

**In my customhandler.php file, I have tried:**

```
// Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

// Get 'Fruits Category' Value.
    $FruitsCategory = $values['fruits_category']; // Multi-value tid

// Get 'Vegetables Category' Value.
    $VegetablesCategory = $values['vegetable_category']; // Multi-value tid

// Get 'Drinks Category' Value.
    $DrinksCategory = $values['drinks_category']; // Multi-value tid

// Put all values in an array().
    $AllItems = array($FruitsCategory,$VegetablesCategory,$DrinksCategory);

// Create a new "Article" node.
    $article = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
        'type' => 'article',        
        'title' => Test,
        'langcode' => 'en',
        'uid' => '1',
        'status' => '1',
        'created' => $current_time,
        'field_article_all_items' => $AllItems,       
        ]);
// Save the created node.
    $article->save();
```

the above code created a new node but with `field_article_all_items` field empty.

**Also I have tried:**

```
// Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

// Get 'Fruits Category' Value.
    $FruitsCategory = $values['fruits_category']; // Multi-value tid

// Get 'Vegetables Category' Value.
    $VegetablesCategory = $values['vegetable_category']; // Multi-value tid

// Get 'Drinks Category' Value.
    $DrinksCategory = $values['drinks_category']; // Multi-value tid

// Put all values in an array().
    $AllItems = array($FruitsCategory,$VegetablesCategory,$DrinksCategory);

// Create a new "Article" node.
    $article = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
        'type' => 'article',        
        'title' => Test,
        'langcode' => 'en',
        'uid' => '1',
        'status' => '1',
        'created' => $current_time,
        //'field_article_all_items' => $AllItems,       
        ]);
// Save the created node.
    $article->save();

foreach ($AllItems as $Item) {
  $article->field_article_all_items[] = $Item;
}

// Save the created node again.
    $article->save();

// Also I have tried the below method.
//   $article->field_article_all_items[] = ['target_id' => $AllItems]

  //Save the created node again.
//   $article->save();
```

But also this code created a new node but with `field_article_all_items` field empty.

How to set the values of `field_article_all_items` equal to `fruits_category` + `vegetable_category` + `drinks_category` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Educated guess: (The key was to merge the arrays by using `array_merge()`)

```
// Put all values in an array().
$AllItems = array_merge($FruitsCategory, $DrinksCategory, $DrinksCategory); // use array_merge

foreach ($AllItems as $Item) {
  $article->field_article_all_items[] = ['target_id' => $Item];
}

$article->save();
```

Also it can be used within the node creation:

```
// Put all values in an array().
    $AllItems = array_merge($FruitsCategory,$VegetablesCategory,$DrinksCategory);

// Create a new "Article" node.
    $article = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
        'type' => 'article',        
        'title' => Test,
        'langcode' => 'en',
        'uid' => '1',
        'status' => '1',
        'created' => $current_time,
        'field_article_all_items' => $AllItems,  // use array_merge
        ]);
// Save the created node.
    $article->save();
```

Comment: to be noted that  `foreach ($AllItems as $Item) {
  $article->field_article_all_items[] = ['target_id' => $Item];
}` will append $allItems to existings, with possible duplication inside `field_article_all_items`